# Google Play Services for AR requires latest version error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, arcore

I am developing an AR Core app for android and was going to test it on a Pixel 4 with Android 11 installed. The phone has the latest version of Google Play Services for AR yet the app does not recognise this and always asks to update it. Even at the update page, there's no button to update as the service is already in the latest version. The app does work on other devices such the Galaxy S20+. Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround to this?

[Google Play Services for AR Update page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQZg.png)

Comment: Downgrading from target/compileSdkVersion 30 back to 29 helped in my case. This is, however, not a real solution, I know.

Comment: In my case, one app is working smooth and another app is causing this issue!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? This is happening in my app for multiple different devices that is running android 11, including but not limited to: Motorola moto g(8) power, Samsung Galaxy A52 5G, Samsung Galaxy S10e,  Samsung Galaxy S21+ 5G

Answer (score 8):

Most likely you commented out

> dependencies {
> …
> implementation 'com.google.ar:core:' }

From https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore at the time of writing that is still needed.

Comment: in my case, I had this dependency, but I had to update it. My version was `1.13.0` and the available one was `1.29.0`, after the update the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You have not updated the Google Play services for AR app or the device memory is full
too many times. The other reason could be that the smartphone device that you are using is too hot or has memory problems. The software such as Google Play services for AR can also crash involuntarily because of memory problems or if the phone's system is unable to perform well, which can be the reason for the problems like AR not being compatible with Google play services.

Sometimes editing for a long time may cause a problem with the app. But, you can simply just close the app to avoid the error and reopen to see if it is functioning. For closing it completely, you must remove it from the working tabs on your smartphone as well.

Restart Your Phone
If the AR is still not working even after doing the previous step, just restart your phone. Sometimes an app malfunctions because the phone is heated or there are a lot of working apps. To restart, long-press the Screen Lock button on the side of your phone and choose 'Restart.' As soon the phone starts, check if the app error persists.
what i would do last is try to Clear Cache
Clearing cache would help to reduce weight on the app and the excessive space it occupies in the device. To clear cache from Google Play Services for AR app:

Open Settings App
Tap on Apps & Notifications
Now, tap on Storage and then on Clear Cache
Reinstall the App
Reinstalling the apps that are not working can stop the malfuction completely. Reinstalling Google Play Services for AR should also trick google into thinking everything is the latest update (even though you said it is, an issue may require a bit of trickery to get it to work). First, uninstall the app from your Android smartphone and then go to the Play Store to install the app. After installing, check again if the app is compatible or not.

i also found this under 'Details on Google Play Services for AR Apks:'
' Automatic updates ensure that apps with AR functionality work without requiring an additional download. Install this service and unlock new ways to shop, learn, create and experience the world together. If your smartphone device does not support Google Play Services for AR, then wait for Google to add your device in their extensive library.'
that may be your final answer, contact support to see if they can speed up the process because otherwise you will have to just wait

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually have formatted the phone just to make sure there is not cache issues and such. There's virtually nothing else on the phone other than the app I deployed. I also made sure there's not heat issues but nothing was working. Funny thing was that this was working until a recent android update.

Comment: Many thanks, indeed i believe that is a problem you should put forward to the google team as they have stated on multiple occasions throughout my research that updates should be fluid on all systems and that seems not to be the case for you

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from target/compileSdkVersion 30 back to 28 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade one of these things then the others have to be upgraded to match:

1. Android Studio
2. Google Play Services for AR
3. Device Operating system