# The application has to have the last version of Google Play for AR

Tags: android, arcore

I have an application that is using ARCore (android), after I have updated the targetSdk version from 29 to 30 I see that some of the devices get the notification (when the app is started) that it is required to update the Google Play for AR, but I don't have any update for the AR, looks like I have the last version of it.

It happens only for some devices, for example for Pixel 4XL, however, it works perfectly on Samsung Note 9

What is a possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. According to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68255789/5709159

it was needed to update this dependency

> dependencies { … implementation 'com.google.ar:core:' }

My version was 1.13.0 and the available one was 1.29.0, after the update, the problem is gone